# Empty image view on creating the file from Uri

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, uri

Capturing image through Camera intent => 
`new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);`

1. Converting Uri to string => `String image = photoUri.toString();`
2. Retrieving Uri from same string => `Uri uri = Uri.parse(image);`
3. Creating file from Uri => `File imageFile = new File(uri.getPath());`

Camera intent works fine but the end file i.e `imageFile` is an empty image file.

Comment: have you checked file size?

Comment: "Creating file from Uri => File imageFile = new File(uri.getPath());" -- that is likely to be incorrect. Please edit your question and show how you are assigning a value to `photoUri`. Also, steps #1 and #2 are pointless, as all they do is give you `photoUri` back.

Comment: I'm creating a file **imageFile**

and creating photoUri as `FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, mActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", imageFile)`

Comment: @pskink I'm trying to upload the image file to the server. Image is successfully displayed in the specified ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
File imageFile = new File(getPath(uri));
public String getPath(Uri uri) 
{
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String realPath = cursor.getString(index);
            cursor.close();
            return realPath;
        }`

I tried this but getting index -1 i.e DATA in not available

Comment: error at line `int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);` it says **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist**

Comment: are you sure you are getting proper uri value?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create the file from the URI, the challenge that I faced was I was getting the URI in format `content://`

So I tried with the following:

`MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri)` which returned me the bitmap so I had choise to use `imageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri))` if I want to show the image in `ImageView` or use following code to create the file out of the bitmat as below:

`FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
 BufferedOutputStream bOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos); //compress format JPEG
 bos.flush();
 bos.close();`